# Copying string failure in Fortran

Tags: string, fortran

I would like to have a procedure which makes a local copy `b` of input character `a` (of not assumed length) into an allocatable array of characters. I do have the following code

```
program test_copystr

   character(len=6) :: str
   str = 'abc'
   call copystr(str)

contains

   subroutine copystr(a)
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: a
      !> Local variables
      integer :: i
      character, allocatable  :: b(:)
      allocate(b(len_trim(a)))
      do i=1, len_trim(a)
         b(i) = a(i:i)
      end do
      print *, b
      b(1:len_trim(a)) = a(1:len_trim(a))
      print *, b
   end subroutine copystr  

end program test_copystr
```

where I'm trying to assign `a` to `b` in two different ways. The result is

> abc
>
> aaa

I thought that both assignments should yield the same output. Can anyone explain me that difference? (To compile this code I'm using gfortran 5.2.0 compiler.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know `b` is an array of characters while `a` is a scalar; when the subroutine is called it is a 6-character string.  These are different things.  The statement

```
  b(1:len_trim(a)) = a(1:len_trim(a))
```

specifies the array section `b(1:3)` on the lhs, that is all 3 elements of `b`, and the substring `a(1:3)` on the rhs.  Now, when assigning a substring of length 3 to a single character such as any element of `b` Fortran assigns only the first character of the string.

In this case every element of `b` is set to the first character of `a`.  It is as if the compiler generates the 3 statements

```
  b(1) = 'abc'
  b(2) = 'abc'
  b(3) = 'abc'
```

to implement the array assignment.  This is what Fortran's array syntax does with an array on the lhs and a scalar (expression) on the rhs, it broadcasts the scalar to each element of the array.

The first method you use, looping across the elements of `b` and the characters of `a` is the regular way make an array of characters equivalent to a string.  But you  could try `transfer` -- see my answer to this question  [Removing whitespace in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179549/removing-whitespace-in-string/27180164#27180164)